# Генерация случайного числа с плавающей запятой в диапазоне

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Пытаюсь сгенерировать случайные числа в диапазоне, но они получаются с маленьким диапазоном и не доходят до верхних границ

```
float random(float a, float b){
    //[a,b]
    return a + static_cast <float> (rand()) /( static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/(b-a)) );
}

int main(){
    srand( time(NULL) );
    printf("random %f", random (-3,1));
    return 0;
}
```

Как исправить, чтобы числа были случайными с хорошим распределением?

Comment: Что такое случайное и псевдослучайное число в вашем понимании, чем они конкретно отличаются для вашей прикладной задачи?

Comment: Вы правы, не правильно написал. к примеру если диапазон от -5 до 1 выходит около 2,5 и может быть больше на 1 или меньше. Не выходят целые значения из диапазона

Comment: Пожалуйста, вносите уточнения сразу в тело вопроса (кнопка "править")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше всего не мучиться со старым `rand()`, а прибегнуть к [возможностям C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution):

```
float random(float a, float b)
{
    static mt19937 gen(random_device{}()); 
    uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(a,b);
    return dis(gen);
}
```

См. [пример](https://ideone.com/FGSjrt).

Comment: у меня появляются одни и те же числа

Comment: @kaliarty, здесь написано почему: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device

Comment: А **как** вы сделали? Точно, как я написал? И появляются подряд одни и те же, или при разных запусках программы?

Comment: @Harry да,появляются одни и те же значения при разных запусках и после пересборки MinGW 32

Comment: Ну, тогда попробуйте `static mt19937 gen(time(0));`, может, реализация `random_device` у MinGW кривовата...

Comment: Даа, заработало. Только странно, что random_device по другому себя ведет. Теперь буду мучаться с тем какие еще могут быть подводные камни у MinGW